# Selenium / Python - Open browser faster

Tags: python, selenium

I have a small question (can't find an answer anywhere)

How to LOAD the chrome browser quicker? (as if I do multiple processes concurrently (small ones) the majority of the time spent for LOADING the browser)

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) 
browser.get(url)
```

Comment: If you want to make it faster you can do headless browser testing. Note in this you want be able to see your test case execution in UI. Suggesting this As i am not sure of any known way where we can make page load faster through scripting.

Comment: @rahulrai yes, headless will improve a bit, but not as much sadly..... me neither... ) that's why I'm asking.... maybe someone will say "Ah.. this is the new way to do it :) "